# Set variable in Map Netlogo

Tags: list, dictionary, iteration, netlogo

I'm trying to figure out how to use map in Netlogo to assign age-group (from a list of age groups) to turtles based on a random choice made by the turtles.

First I compare their choice to a list of choice ranges, and then assign to the corresponding age-group.

```
let choice random-float 1
  show ( map [ [ x y ] -> choice < x   
    ask turtles [set age-group y] ] [0.11 0.25 0.36 0.48 0.55] [1 2 3 4 5])
```

However, I'm getting an error message: *Expected closing bracket*. Can't seem to figure out what the issue is

I felt the above is a better approach to the code I wrote below, which seems repetitive:

```
ask turtles [
    let choice random-float 1
         (ifelse
               choice < 0.11 [ set age-group 1 ]
               choice < 0.25 [ set age-group 2 ]
               choice < 0.36 [ set age-group 3 ]
               choice < 0.48 [ set age-group 4 ]
               choice < 0.55 [ set age-group 5 ]
               ...
               ...

               [ set age-group 100 ])
  ]
```

This second approach works but gets longer and repetitive as the number of age-groups increases. Any insights on using map to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you're getting the bracket error, but I can't see how the function would work anyway since you are only drawing the random number once and then using that same random number for all the turtles. There is a weighted draw primitive in NetLogo in the `rnd` extension, see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/index2.html

However, I have a model that I don't use extensions and instead have a utility procedure I use for this since I need to do list based random weighted draws a lot. It looks like this:

```
to-report draw-wtd [#vals #wts]  ; weighted draw from list of values
  if length #vals != length #wts [ print "ERROR: weighted random draw" report -1 ]
  let draw random-float sum #wts
  let idx 0
  while [draw > 0]
  [ set draw draw - item idx #wts
    set idx idx + 1
  ]
  report item (idx - 1) #vals
end
```

It's essentially the`ifelse` version of your code except that it's built into a while loop so you can provide it with different lists. Then you can simply have:

```
ask turtles
[ set age-group draw-wtd [1 2 3 4 5] [0.11 0.25 0.36 0.48 0.55]
]
```